# If output comes in negative value, how to make it null?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin

Hi I am working on one query, what I want to do is, whenever output comes in negative value,
I want to make it null, following is my query, can anyone help me with this ?

```
select (to_char((coalesce(14515200/3600000,0) - (coalesce(30512.65/3600,0) - (coalesce(1800/3600,0) + (coalesce(1800/3600,0))))),'FM99,999,999,999'))::character varying as test
```

Comment: Use `GREATEST(..., 0)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe select (to_char(GREATEST(coalesce(14515200/3600000,0) - (coalesce(30512.65/3600,0) - (coalesce(1800/3600,0) + (coalesce(1800/3600,0)))),0),'FM99,999,999,999'))::character varying as absenteeism

it is giving 0 as output, I want to display null, not 0

Comment: Then add another `NULLIF()`.

Comment: I did not get where to add null if ? can you add as answer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a result of NULL for negative values, use

```
nullif(greatest(/* your expression */, 0), 0)
```

The only drawback here is that a result of exactly 0 will also become NULL. If you want to avoid that, you could use a user defined function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION neg_to_null(double precision) RETURNS double precision
   LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
'BEGIN; RETURN CASE WHEN $1 < 0.0 THEN NULL ELSE $1; END;';
```

I use PL/pgSQL to avoid function inlining.

Comment: Wouldn't this give NULL if one of your values was actually 0? That might not be desired.

Comment: @deed02392 True. I have added an alternative that avoids that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Move your logic to the `from` clause and use `case`:

```
select (case when test_n >= 0 then test_n::character varying end)
from (select . . .  as test_n -- your expression as number) x
```

If your expression actually uses values from a table, you can use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join to define `test_n`.